# How to get the card ID using nfc(android studio)

Tags: java, android

Good day, I can not get indifikator maps, how can this be done?
Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent");

    // check for NFC related actions
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        TextView lata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        lata.setText(tag.toString());

        Tag tag1 = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        byte[] id = tag.getId();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed with the below lines of codes to get the tag ID:

```
  StringBuilder tagInfo = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] tagId = tag.getId();

        for (byte aTagId : tagId) {
            tagInfo.append(Integer.toHexString(aTagId & 0xFF)).append(" ");
        }
        tagInfo.append("\n");
```

to also get the techlist of the card

```
 String[] techList = tag.getTechList();

        tagInfo.append("\nTech List\n");
        tagInfo.append("length = " + techList.length + "\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < techList.length; i++) {
            tagInfo.append(techList[i] + "\n ");
        }
```

then you can do `tagInfo.toString().trim();`and use set the tagInfo to your textview to display the data.